# Package MySql.Data 6.9.8 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I was thinking about trying to get MySQL working with my ASP.NET Core application and so I added `"MySql.Data": "6.9.8"` to my project.json dependencies.

Doing so and running `dotnet restore` I get `Package MySql.Data 6.9.8 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0`

I think this means that the MySQL ADO provider doesn't work with .NET Core, am I right? (Oh, and I'm not even talking Entity Framework here) Any way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding "net46" within project.json

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "net46",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package v 6.10 available on Nuget as a fix for this problem.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.10.0-alpha

This is in alpha phase i hope soon the release version come.

Comment: Thank you! Now i can use it.